# Is the format be+on+trial grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-structure

See, for example, the following example;

> He **is on trial** for selling illicit goods in his store.

Is that sentence grammatically sound or should it better be like;

> He **is *put* on trial** for selling illicit goods in his store.

? According to Google N-grams, the original is more frequent. See [is on trial,is put on trial](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20on%20trial%2Cis%20put%20on%20trial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20trial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20put%20on%20trial%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20trial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20put%20on%20trial%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is on trial" is the common phrase and perfectly correct. The passive "is put" is odd in the example you give, using the present tense. The verb "put" indicates a single act, but you want to talk about an ongoing state. You could "put" in the past tense:

> John is on trial for murder
>
> John was put on trial for murder three weeks ago.

Comment: One possible use for "is put" would be narrative present tense, telling a story: "He goes on the run, the police track him down and catch him one morning and he **is put on trial** the very same day."  The more ordinary uses are exactly as James says.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-trial), it's perfectly fine and grammatically correct.

> **on trial** [phrase]
>
> If someone **is on trial**, they are being tried in a court of law.
>  
>   *He is currently on trial accused of serious assault.*
>
> **on trial** [phrase]
>
> If you say that someone or something **is on trial**, you mean that they
>   are in a situation where people are observing them to see whether they
>   succeed or fail.
>  *The President will be drawn into a damaging battle in
>   which his credentials will **be on trial***.

Comment: And, would putting 'put' before 'on trial' change the meaning?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli As JamesK has pointed, it sonds odd if you use the present tense "is put on trial". He has pointed a good example, use it to mark an specific point in time in the past.